# Calculate width of a div based on steps with SASS

Tags: css, sass

Here is the situation:

I have a step div that contains a dynamic number of step elements. (2, 3, 4)

What I want to do is to calculate the width to apply to each `step` element dynamically:

- 2 steps: 50%
- 3 steps: 33.3%
- 4 steps: 25%
- etc...

I already managed to generate the number display on the step dynamically based on the SASS `counter`.

But I don't know how to know the number of steps from SASS. What I need is to know the max steps and then divide the width by the steps number.

Here is a picture of the result: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByzbHcAxmCyveWp1RUhCb0pxSmc

```
body {
  .steps {
    background-color: $gray-lighter;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    .steps_container {
      width: 300px;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;

      /*progressbar*/
      ul#progressbar {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
        counter-reset: step;
        padding-left: 0;

        li {
          list-style-type: none;
          color: $gray-dark;
          font-size: 12px;
          width: 33.33%;// HERE is what I want to change to: width: 100% / $steps
          float: left;
          position: relative;
          line-height: 1;

          &:before {
            @include border-all-radius (15px);
            content: counter(step);// Display the current step number. 
            counter-increment: step;// Auto increment.
            width: 28px;
            height: 28px;
            line-height: 20px;
            display: block;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: $white;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: $gray-dark;
            margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 100 !important;
            padding-top: 3px;
            border:1px solid $gray-darker;
          }

          &.active {
            @extend .fa;
            color: $gray-darker;

            &:before {
              background-color: $orange;
              counter: none;
            }
          }

          &.success {
            @extend .fa;
            color: $gray-darker;

            &:before {
              background-color: $green-check;
              content: "\f00c";
              counter: none;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      #progressbar li:after {
        content: '';
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background: $gray-darker;
        position: absolute;
        left: -50%;
        top: 12px;
        z-index: 99; /*put it behind the numbers*/
      }

      #progressbar li:first-child:after {
        /*connector not needed before the first step*/
        content: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to work out the CSS necessary to achieve this effect.  Sass is only capable of generating CSS, it doesn't know anything about the DOM.

Comment: try with `display:table` on `ul` and `display: table-cell` on `li`

Comment: To automatically center? Hum, that could do the trick. I'll try, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something similar to this but to achieve this I had to dynamically output (either via javascript or whatever backend technology you are using) a class based on the number of steps bring displayed., i.e. if two steps are being displayed, a class called step-2 would be outputted. If this is possible you can do something like the code provide below:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10{
    .step-#{$i} {
        width: 100% / $i
    }
}
```

it would output:

```
.step-1 { width: 100%;}
.step-2 { width: 50%}
ect......
```

Depending on the number of steps being displayed the correct width would be applied. Hope this helps you and guides you in the right direction.

----------------------using JS to count the number of list items--------------

```
var countListItems = document.getElementsByClassName("list").length;
var d = document.getElementById("listContainer");
d.className = d.className+" step-"+countListItems ;
```

Each list item would have a class of ".list" and the ul would have an id of "#listContainer"

Comment: It helps, but how can I calculate the number of `<li>`, so the number of steps? I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: What kind of platform are you using for development(drupal or wordpress)? or do you want to do it with js?

Comment: I use Ruby on Rails, I was looking for a way to do it dynamically with SASS, since I don't know too much this language and its possibilities, if I can't I'll do it in javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot manipulate the DOM with sass but you should be able to add a class fromt he backend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210614/how-to-change-html-output-based-on-values-in-rails

Comment: If you want to find the number of list items via js you can do something like this: http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/jbgFG

Comment: That's what I thought, but SASS impressionned me with the programmation side, like the condition and so on, so I was hoping that maybe it would have been possible. let's do taht in j so, but i prefer jQuery :p Thanks.